# Unable to add --grep inside .gitconfig

Tags: git

I'm not able to create an alias with the grep command in the gitconfig. 
When the following line is added, I start getting an error while running the alias.

```
log --grep="BUILD\|Public Changes" --invert-grep
```

Basically my intent is to avoid BUILD and Public Changes from the list of git commit messages.

EDIT:
This works when running from git cmdline:

```
git log --grep="BUILD\|Public Changes" --invert-grep
```

But this (in the gitconfig) gives an error:

```
ls = log --grep="BUILD\|Public Changes" --invert-grep
```

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

The error (not listed in the question) is

```
fatal: bad config file line 8 in .git/config
```

I fixed this first by removing that from `.git/config` and then running the following command:

```
git config alias.ls 'log --grep="BUILD\|Public Changes" --invert-grep'
```

The configuration file it generates looks like this:

```
[alias]
    ls = log --grep=\"BUILD\\|Public Changes\" --invert-grep
```

It seems that both the quotes and backslash needed to be escaped to be valid syntax

Here is the command working (`GIT_TRACE=1` so you can see the alias resolution)

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git ls --format=%h
18:08:47.310940 git.c:561               trace: exec: 'git-ls' '--format=%h'
18:08:47.310989 run-command.c:334       trace: run_command: 'git-ls' '--format=%h'
18:08:47.311393 git.c:278               trace: alias expansion: ls => 'log' '--grep=BUILD|Public Changes' '--invert-grep'
18:08:47.311462 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'log' '--grep=BUILD|Public Changes' '--invert-grep' '--format=%h'
18:08:47.311680 run-command.c:334       trace: run_command: 'pager'
18:08:47.311856 run-command.c:193       trace: exec: 'pager'
a081dfd
```